# Pass another data than the id in the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, scaffolding

I'm currently creating a website that would allow a visitor to read a magazine online. I created a scaffold for the magazine itself, and another one for the pages, which belongs to the magazine. This way, I can create a multi upload for the pages while creating the magazine, and everything gets uploaded in the same time.

When I nest the pages resources inside the magazine's resources, as following:

```
resources :magazines do 
  resources :pages
end
```

I get "`domain.com/magazines/<slug>/pages/id`"

However, I had some issues with the id, because it can't be used to count the pages (since the id never goes back to 1), so I created a function inside the controller that would count the pages for me, and save each pages with a "page_number" value.

My question is the following: how, instead of the id, can I kindly ask my router to use the :page_number ?
I tried to create a custom route, which looked like this

```
resources :magazines do
  get '/:page_number' => 'pages#show', as: :custom_page
end
```

But for an unknown reason, Rails tells me that my custom route simply doesn't exist, even though it exists when I type `rake routes`

Thank you in advance

**Edit**

Here is my **magazine_controller.rb**

```
class MagazinesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_magazine, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @magazines = Magazine.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @magazine = Magazine.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @magazine = Magazine.new(magazine_params)

    if @magazine.save
      if params[:images]
        (params[:image] || []).each_with_index do |image, index|
          @magazine.pages.create(image: image, page_number: index + 1)
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    if @magazine.update(magazine_params)
      if params[:images]
        params[:images].each { |image|
          @magazine.pages.create(image: image)
        }
      end
      redirect_to @magazine, notice: 'Magazine was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @magazine.destroy
    redirect_to magazines_url, notice: 'Magazine was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def set_magazine
    @magazine = Magazine.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def magazine_params
    params.require(:magazine).permit(:titre, :apercu)
  end

end
```

and here is **page_controller.rb**

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    if @page.save
      redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @page.update(page_params)
      redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @page.destroy
    redirect_to :back, notice: 'Page was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  private

  def set_page
    @page = Page.find(params[:id])
  end

  def page_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:titre, :apercu)
  end

end
```

**Edit 2**

Here is the output from development.log when trying to reach the page

```
Started GET "/magazines/magazine-54/pages/11" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-12-12 11:04:45 +0100
Processing by PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"magazine_id"=>"magazine-54", "id"=>"11"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `pages' for nil:NilClass):

app/controllers/pages_controller.rb:49:in `set_page'
  Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (2.4ms)
  Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendering /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (13.8ms)
```

Comment: You can use `:id` param and pass page number instead of id. Then instead of `Page.find(params[:id])` you can call something like `magazine.pages.find_by(page_number: params[:id])`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried it but I got the following error: `NameError (undefined local variable or method 'magazine' for PageController, did you mean? magazine_url)`. So I tried with `magazine_url` instead of `magazine`, but now it doesn't recognizes `pages`. However I can still see that it tries to get the id as a parameter instead of the page_number

Comment: `magazine` is just pseudo code, I don't know your controller code to post working code. Replace `magazine` with variable that you are storing `Magazine` object in

Comment: I edited my question with the magazine_controller

Comment: Can you show `PagesController`? I think this issue is related only to this controller not `MagazineController`

Comment: Question edited, thank you for your time !

Answer (score 1):

With these routes

```
resources :magazines do 
  resources :pages
end
```

you should be able to update `PagesController` and add/update following methods:

```
def magazine
  @magazine = Magazine.find(params[:magazine_id])
end

def page
  @page = @magazine.pages.find_by(page_number: params[:id])
end
```

to make it work you should have `page_number` column in `Page` model and `has_many :pages` association in `Magazine` model

Comment: I actually already have the required stuff in my models / columns, however, I tried your code and got `undefined method 'pages' for nil:NilClass`. It seems that even thought I defined @magazine just above, it still doesn't know what it means just after that...

Comment: Can you paste output from console when you perform request to controller?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you want me to do, do you want the full trace of the request?

Comment: I mean the output from development.log that you receive when requesting `PagesController` and getting `undefined method 'pages' for nil:NilClass` error. I would like to see request params if possible

Comment: Sure thing, I edited my question with the logs inside, thank you again!

Comment: Ah I didn't noticed that you are using slug. So instead of `@magazine = Magazine.find(params[:magazine_id])` you can use `@magazine = Magazine.find_by(slug: params[:magazine_id])` - of course put there right name for slug column, I assumed that it's called `slug`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130394/discussion-between-jaeger-and-dziamber).